Rsuite date picker hides behind mui drawer
Hello so I saw a similar issue behind a Dialog Popup but that fix did not work for me does anyone have any clue what i could do?
enter link description here
The datepicker popup just goes behind the drawer like seen on the bellow screenshot. Ive tired to edit the zIndex for both drawer and datepicker
enter link description here
import React, { useState ,useEffect} from 'react';
import {
Box,
Typography,
TextField,
Button,
SvgIcon,
Drawer,
Divider,
IconButton,
Slider,
Chip,
} from '@mui/material';
import CheckCircleIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/solid/CheckCircleIcon';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import XMarkIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/outline/XMarkIcon';
import ArrowPathIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/outline/ArrowPathIcon';

import CalendarDaysIcon from '@heroicons/react/24/outline/CalendarDaysIcon';
import { DateRangePicker } from 'rsuite';
import 'rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css'; 

const FilterDrawer = ({
  drawerOpen,
  toggleDrawer,
  selectedDate,
  setSelectedDate,
}) => {
  const [localSelectedDate, setLocalSelectedDate] = useState(selectedDate);


useEffect(() => {
 setLocalSelectedDate(selectedDate);
}, [selectedDate]);

const handleDateChange = (dateRange) => {
 setLocalSelectedDate(dateRange);
};




useEffect(() => {
           setLocalSelectedDate(selectedDate); 
}, [ selectedDate]);

return (
    <Drawer anchor="right" open={drawerOpen} onClose={toggleDrawer}>
        <Box sx={{ width: 350, padding: 2 }}>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Select filters</Typography>
                <Box>
                    <IconButton onClick={resetFilters}>
                        <SvgIcon><ArrowPathIcon /></SvgIcon>
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton onClick={toggleDrawer}>
                        <SvgIcon><XMarkIcon /></SvgIcon>
                    </IconButton>

                </Box>
            </Box>
                            <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>Date</Typography>
            <Divider sx={{ mb: 2, mt: 1 }} />
            <Box sx={{ my: 2 }}>
            <DateRangePicker
             size='md'
        format="yyyy-MM-dd"
        block
        showOneCalendar
        appearance="default" // Or any other appearance you prefer
        placeholder="Select Date Range"
        value={localSelectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        style={{ width: '100%',zIndex: 10000000000}}
        placement='bottomEnd'
        preventOverflow
        
      />
            </Box>


            </Box>
        </Box>
    </Drawer>
);};export default FilterDrawer;

